# IOS app enter background but view not reload

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want develop a app of password manager,enter the application,you need to enter password to login. when the app enter background and enter foreground,then you need enter password again.
I resign the notification `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`, `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`, `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and I reload the view in the implement method, but it does not work. the app must enter foreground then the view reload.
And when double click home, the password was discover. It was not I want, what can I do for this.
The Similar application:
https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/mi-ma-zhang-hao-guan-jia-quan/id547904729?mt=8

I'm very sorry for my bad English.
I want to implement like this: I add a green view on the window when the application enter background. but when the app enter foreground, the view begin change green. I want when the app enter foreground, the view was already green, or double click home button on ios7, the app thumbnails was green.
code like this in appDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.window addSubview:view];
}
```

thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what you're trying to do without providing an example in the form of an app I have to download to my device (and is in a language extremely foreign to me).  I don't understand the exact issue...

Comment: You want to reload a view when the application enters the background but its not working?  Show us your code and we can help.

Comment: code like this in appDelegate.m

    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self.window addSubview:view];
    }

Comment: Stop backgrounsd running mode of application by set

Application doesn't run in background = yes

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are looking , but still from what i understand , You need to write the code in 'applicationWillEnterForeground' if you prefer reloading the view only after user entered foreground

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```